# How to correctly set an external path on SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I'm trying to set an external path on SVN. Here is what I do in SVN:

1. Right click on folder where I want an external
2. Select "Show Properties"
3. New -> Externals
4. In "Externals", I click New
5. At local path, I tried setting the path I wanted, but whatever I set, when I update the files, it adds the path I wrote to the folder which I added the external. For example my folder on SVN is "Externals". If I set Local path to `^/trunk/external`, when I'll commit it tries to fetch files from `(all the long path before)/Externals/^/trunk/Externals`. How do I tell it that the local path is the current directory? If I set nothing, it complains, if I set `./` it complains...
6. For the URL where to fetch files from, it sometimes works when I set a file, but not a folder?

Note: I used [this site](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) but unfortunately, the part where I have trouble just says:

> To add a new external, click the New... and then fill in the **required** information in the shown dialog.

I read the tips afters but they don't help... If someone has a concrete example it would help a lot.

Comment: You cannot put the files of a external in the _current_ directory. You should put it one directory up. The directory you want the externals in, should not be created.

Comment: Since you are apparently using Tortoise, you would do well to tag this as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the dialog from TortoiseSVN that you're having difficulties with:

[image: Tortoise SVN New External definition dialog]

Here, *Local Path* refers to the file or folder relative to the folder that has this externals property set on it.  So, if I had a folder at ^/trunk/Externals that I wanted to exist here as well, I'd set it up as follows:

- **Local Path:** Externals *(note that it must not exist in the current directory; it will be created)*
- **URL:** ^/trunk/Externals

This is setting a property (as you can see from the title bar) on the folder C:\Sources\Ops.  The result is that updating C:\Sources\Ops will pull the  contents of the ^/trunk/Externals folder in SVN into C:\Sources\Ops\Externals.

Comment: thanks a lot! But now it says : The specified path has an unexpected status.

Comment: Make sure the folder that the externals are going into should not be checked into SVN.  In my example, C:\Sources\Ops\Externals should not be already be on SVN.

Comment: nice! exactly! It didn't work the way I though it would. I though it would add file in an existing folder. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I edited your answer to add a comment about the fact that the file will be created. If you mind it feel free to reject it!!

Comment: Good idea. I tweaked the style just a bit. Thanks!